# Editng Table Rows by row index

Tags: angular

I am a beginner and I want to know how to edit a table row by using the index of the item to be edited. Is it also possible for me to use jquery to get the index of the item on the row because I am trying to use the function `trashGame()` to find the id of a particular item and it doesn't work. Every row has its edit button on the table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=3>Games</th>
    <th>No of Players</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>

  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let game of Games; let row_no = index">
      <td>{{row_no + 1}}</td>
      <td>{{game.id}}</td>
      <td>{{game.name}}</td>
      <td>{{game.no_of_players}}</td>
      <td><button class="deleteBtn" (click)="trashGame()">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my service :

```
removeGame(id) {
    return this.http.delete('url ' + id)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .subscribe(
             data => console.log(data)   
      );
}
```

Game component:

```
trashGame () {
    // get id of the game 

   var index = 

}
```

Comment: Why use jquery when you are obviously working with Angular2?

Comment: Oops.. well i thought that could work anyway

Comment: @BarryMeijer, how can i edit a table row using the index of the item or the item_id ? Assist me if you can please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just as easy that you in your table pass the game you want to delete. Since you are iterating the games, so each row represents a game, and since you have that button on that row, it belongs to that specific game. So simply pass the game as a parameter in your delete-method:

```
<tr *ngFor="let game of Games; let row_no = index">
  <td>{{row_no + 1}}</td>
  <td>{{game.id}}</td>
  <td>{{game.name}}</td>
  <td>{{game.no_of_players}}</td>
  <td><button class="deleteBtn" (click)="trashGame(game)">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

and:

```
trashGame (game) {
  console.log(game.id) 
  // here you can call the service method with your id 
}
```

Nothing more needed :)